# Managing different project configurations in Dynamics AX

Tags: configuration, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We have trouble with keeping apart our different configurations. Allow me to explain with a little

### Scenario:

Let's say you have two AX projects, e.g. **P** and **M**, that both alter the `ProdRouteJob` table, calling methods in one of their own project specific classes.
You have all these classes on your developer machine, of course, and `ProdRouteJob` compiles fine, but for an installation on a new server, you don't want to add stub classes for every non-installed project, do you? So you wrap these calls to project classes in something like

```
if( Global::isConfigurationkeyEnabled( <projectPConfKey> ) )  
     // call project P stuff
```

to encapsulate them cleanly. You declare configuration keys for all your projects, and you're ready to go, right?

However, this throws an error if you haven't installed project **P** on this machine, because its `projectPConfKey` is unknown. Now you could at every installation install configuration keys for all your projects, just to tell the server that there is such a thing as a `projectPConfKey`, but then all these `if`s would evaluate to true...

In short: how do you include configuration keys in your project XPOs so that your code compiles, but at the same time so that some configuration keys are disabled from the start?

Or is there something totally basic that I'm missing here?

### EDIT:

Consensus among the answers (thank you, demas; thank you, Mr. Kjeldsen) is that it's impractical to attempt a more or less automatic client-side configuration via macros or configuration keys. Thus, when we are installing at the client, we will have to import the standard tables with our changes and manually take out all changes not pertinent to the current installation.

I am a bit at a loss which answer to accept, because demas answered the question I asked, while Mr. Kjeldsen answered the questions that arose in the comment conversation under demas' answer. I shall, with apologies to Mr. Kjeldsen, mark demas' answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( Global::isConfigurationkeyEnabled( <projectPConfKey> ) )
```

This check works only execution time and when you compile code you get the error.

So you need create stub classes or compare objects when you import them on production server and import only changes of project M.

There is another one approach but I don't have Axapta to check it. Try:

```
#if.never
someMissingCall();
#endif
```

But i'm not sure that it will works now.

Comment: `#if.never` works: it checks whether a macro called "never" has been defined. So you mean we should just declare macros like "ProjectP" or "ProjectM" in our respective projects and use `#if.ProjectP` to comment out our project specific code parts?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the solutions. But I think that you need to remove this macroses when you install both projects. I just compare objects while importing them to production system and import only needed parts of code.

Comment: Why should we remove the macros when installing both projects? It should work just fine either way, shouldn't it? This macro checking hack certainly is ugly, but hey: if it saves us from having to go through dozens of tables and classes to weed out project specific stuff...

Comment: But how do big solution centres with potentially dozens of projects manage their additions to the standard codebase? Are you saying that they sit down and clean out all mentions of non-installed projects after install? Or do they install a full set of dummy classes first and overwrite them with the real stuff where needed for the projects at hand?

Comment: I work in the big MBS parther and yes - we clean out all mentions of non-installed projects. It is not require much time. Do you look at Compare tool in Axapta?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of: manually going through every standard class or table that we touched at import, to see if the changes are needed for this particular setup. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Big solution centers (VAR) typically have separate applications for each module.
If you have 2 modules, you have 2 applications.

Good modules have very small collision areas to the standard application, these are kept in a separate project.

Collisions with the standard and other modules are then handled manually at install time. As the collision area is small and rarely change (it should not contain buisness logic) the problem is minimal.

Comment: Granted: you always try to minimize your impact on the standard stuff. But still, if these solution centers have a half dozen applications that all alter, say, something in the standard ProdTable, you might end up with several dozen calls to methods that are only present in SOME of their applications. Or do they build each project cleanly on a separate dev server and only merge them at the client?

Comment: "Do they build each project cleanly on a separate dev server and only merge them at the client?" If project equals module, then yes. If project equals "new development for customer XYZ" then no. But in that case all the projects eventually ends at the customer installation anyway, then what's the problem?